# iOS Receiving superview's touches events in it's subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiresponder

**Question:** *Is there a way to receive touches from superview **directly** in it's subview (i.e. touches outside of subview's boundaries)?*

I'd like to avoid delegation (formal/informal), NSNotification, proxy or any other intermediary solution to forward touch events from one to another view.

Comment: No other way. Read theory about UIResponderChain.

Comment: I've read it and it doesn't say directly its impossible. It even suggests that's the question of returning BOOL value of pointInside:withEvent:, quote: "If the point passed into hitTest:withEvent: is not inside the bounds of the view, the first call to the pointInside:withEvent: method returns NO, the point is ignored, and hitTest:withEvent: returns nil."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. Override `pointInside` in the subview. Hopefully direct enough for your requirements.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   point = [self convertPoint:point toCoordinateSpace:self.superview];
    CGRect frame = self.superview.frame;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Much obliged! SKView subclassed with this method works perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've found an issue: sometimes condition is not met but returning unconditionally YES fixes it (?). Any thoughts? 
My UIView tree is: UIView A (root) > UIView B > UIView C > UIView D over SKView in the same node. Receiving touches in SKView from itself and UIView C only.

Comment: @KrzysztofPrzygoda - i expect it is some issue with your view hierarchy but I cannot tell enough from your comment. I suggest you try logging the point and frame to find what condition causes it to fail. See also the apple guide to [event delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html) and also [this nice write-up on smnh.me](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/)

Comment: Thank you for provided link - really nice (whish Apple did that - use cases are something I really feel they missed). I found that easiest solution for me is to override pointInside:withEvent: for always return YES. The only pain thing is that any solution works up to superview but not up to the main/root view. So, I have to subclass every UIView in the tree to the desired hierarchy level.